# Can't seem to get this Box-M test to work

Tags: r

```
wine <- file.choose()
data <- read.csv(wine)
mat <- as.matrix(data)
result <- box_m(mat[,5],mat[,5])
```

It keeps giving the error:

> Error in cov(data[which(group == Levels[i]), ]) :  supply both 'x' and
> 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'

Comment: Please use ``dput(head(data))`` to show us what your data looks like, or else it is hard for people to help.

Comment: Could you please share what does a small sample of your `data` looks like? Also, the name of package from which you are using the function `box_m`. Share output of `dput(head(data))` in your question description.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rstatix::box_m(data[, -5], data[, 5])`, looks like at least one problem is you forgot to make it `-5` here's an example using `iris` no need to explicitly change to a matrix

```r
rstatix::box_m(iris[, -5], iris[, 5])
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   statistic  p.value parameter method                                           
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                                            
#> 1      141. 3.35e-20        20 Box's M-test for Homogeneity of Covariance Matri…
```